# My JPanel is appearing gray

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to make a title screen with buttons, and use a `JFrame` object to have a background as a picture (`BufferedImage`). However, the screen appears gray and only updates parts of the screen when I mouse over the buttons.

The `JFrame` class:

```
//import statements
public class StartGame extends JFrame{
    private JLabel title=new JLabel("Title");
    private JButton start=new JButton("New Game");
    private JButton quit=new JButton("Quit");
    public static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 720;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        StartGame g1=new StartGame();
        g1.play();
    }

    public StartGame(){
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle( "Title" );
        setResizable( false );
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT) );
        setLocation(dim.width/2-getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-getSize().height/2);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setVisible(true);

        StartGamePanel sgp = new StartGamePanel();
        sgp.setSize( StartGame.WIDTH,StartGame.HEIGHT );
        sgp.setLayout( null );
        sgp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        sgp.setVisible(true);

        start.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        start.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        start.setBounds( WIDTH/2-105, HEIGHT/9*6, 210, 40 );
        start.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        quit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);   
        quit.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        quit.setBounds( WIDTH/2-75, HEIGHT/9*8, 150, 40 );
        quit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        title.setBounds( WIDTH/2-216, HEIGHT/8*2, 432, 100 );
        title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        ButtonListener spy = new ButtonListener();
        start.addActionListener( spy );
        quit.addActionListener( spy );

        sgp.add(title);
        sgp.add(start);
        sgp.add(quit);
        getContentPane().add( sgp );
        pack();
    }

    private void play(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource().equals(quit)) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (e.getSource().equals(start)){
                //start
            dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the `JPanel` class:

```
//import statements
public class StartGamePanel extends JPanel{
    private BufferedImage bg;
    public StartGamePanel(){
        setBackground( Color.WHITE );
        setSize( StartGame.WIDTH, StartGame.HEIGHT );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(StartGame.WIDTH, StartGame.HEIGHT) );
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        setLayout( null );

        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("pics/SplashScreen.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println ( "No splash screen image in StartGamePanel" );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
        super.paintComponent( g );

        g.drawImage( bg, 0, 0, null );
    }

    private void play(){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    setVisible(true);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I'm fairly sure that the issue lies within the `JPanel` class, as I am able to replace it with another `JPanel` class from a different part of my program, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't Place `setVisible(true);` at the start or you need to `repaint();` it afterwards.

Because it have a time to update for those adds at the bottom, this is why your program is gray or the default color of Java Application.